# Problema al cerrar toggle menú

Tags: jquery, responsive, menu

Tengo un menú responsivo que funciona con anclas dentro de mi sitio, el problema es que al dar clic en una opción (li), no se cierra, debes dar clic en la (x) para cerrarlo. Por favor, espero puedan ayudarme, este es mi código en jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hamburger').click(function() {
        $('.hamburger').toggleClass('is-active');
        $('.menuppal').toggleClass('is_active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="hamburger">
        <div class="_layer -top"></div>
        <div class="_layer -mid"></div>
        <div class="_layer -bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="menuppal">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#principal">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a></li>
          <li><a href="#fruta">Frutos Rojos UltraOrganics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#biodegradable">Nuestro empaque</a></li>
          <li><a href="#porque">&iquest;Por qu&eacute;?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#recetas">Recetas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#ultraorganicsproductos">M&aacute;s productos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega otro evento click a los enlaces, para que eliminen la clase 'is_active' de '.menuppal' al darles click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hamburger').click(function() {
        $('.hamburger').toggleClass('is-active');
        $('.menuppal').toggleClass('is_active');
        return false;
    });
    // evento click para eliminar la clase is_active
    $('.'.menuppal a').click(function() {
       $('.menuppal').removeClass('is_active');
    };
});
```

Comment: Si bien puede ser la respuesta, seria mejor agregar una explicacion de lo que se cambio o agrego para que el OP u otros usuarios entiendan el codigo

Comment: Gracias Elboy, funcionó de lujo